# JSF <h:selectManyCheckbox> check box editable issue

Tags: jsf

I want to make my checkboxes non editable dynamically using `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`. I have set `editable="true"` property in my code. But this is working inconsistently. Could you please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` on `onclick`.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox onclick="return false;">
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply..but with disabled="true" also it is working inconsistently like some times noneditable is coming and some times it is not coming.Is this a bug in selectManyCheckbox?

Comment: No, JSF does only what your code tells it to do. Likely your bean is request scoped and the property is not correctly preserved.

Comment: This is the code ..<h:selectManyCheckbox id="mandids" value="#{clientB2BPref.mandQueueIds}" layout="pageDirection" disabled="true"> <f:selectItems value="#{clientB2BPref.bkgMandQueues}"/> </h:selectManyCheckbox> ..i have to dispaly these check boxes always non editable..but it is not working consistently..some time it is coming as ediatble with ticked and some times non editable with ticked.

Comment: Oh, you want to disable the ticking? See updated answer. The `disabled="true"` only prevents changes being sent to the server.

Comment: for achieving this do i need to add any extra property?

Comment: No. Why this comment? Didn't `onclick="return false;"` work for you? What JSF impl/version and browser are you using?

Comment: onclick="return false;"  is missing in ur previous post..let me chk with this..thanks

Comment: It's just the answer straight here above. I have just edited it. Click the link behind "edited" to see edit history.

Comment: still not working with this code ...<h:selectManyCheckbox id="mandids" value="#{clientB2BPref.mandQueueIds}" layout="pageDirection" onclick="return false;" ><f:selectItems value="#{clientB2BPref.bkgMandQueues}"/> </h:selectManyCheckbox>

Comment: Hi Balu,Please help me to reolve this issue